# Regular expression to match MySQL timestamp format "Y-M-D H:M:S"

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression to match a string holding a date in the MySQL timestamp format, ex "2012-07-16 02:04:33".

It is not as easy as it sounds, e.g. you should not end up with February 30th.

I know there are easier ways to do this, but I am depending on being able to pass a string and a regular expression to evaluate that string.

I would be glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The regular expression:

```
/^(((\d{4})(-)(0[13578]|10|12)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(-)(0[469]|1‌​1)(-)([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(-)(02)(-)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|(([02468]‌​[048]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([13579][26]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][0][48])(-)(0‌​2)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][2468][048])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][13579][26])(-)(02‌​)(-)(29)))(\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))$/
```

does the job. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Good to see that you posted the answer that solved your problem to help the next chap that comes along!

Comment: This answer is incorrect using datetime string '2013-11-27 14:43:29'. http://codepad.viper-7.com/sOTV9U

Comment: 'codepad.viper-7.com/sOTV9U –  a coder' is right.  It does fail with a few dates including '2013-11-27 14:43:29'. I found a few typos and fixed it: `/^(((\d{4})(-)(0[13578]|10|12)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(-)(0[469]|11)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(-)(02)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|2[0-8]))|(([02468][048]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([13579][26]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][0][48])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][2468][048])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][13579][26])(-)(02)(-)(29)))(\s)(([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))$/`   Thanks henrikstroem. This helped me out a ton!! :)

Comment: Btw I tested my correction with every day string starting from `0000-01-01 00:00:00` all the way up to `2015-07-01 00:00:00`  (about 737,000 date strings in total). I generated the dates using the Carbon library and it passed so it seems to handle leap years well.

Comment: The regex itself is correct, but when I copy-pasted it and tried it out, it didn't work! After testing it for sometime, it seems that your code includes some html entities like `&zwnj;` and `&#8203;`

Answer (score 10):

You should do it in 2 steps, instead of trying to use really complicated regexes.

**Step1:** Check if the format is right using regex.
Use something like

`/^\d\d\d\d-(\d)?\d-(\d)?\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/g`

**Step2:** If it is a match, use something similar to `strtotime()` in PHP (or parse using date-time functions in whichever language you are using) and check if the result is valid, to eliminate dates like February 30th.

Comment: Well, it's not really what I am looking for. I generally agree to the approach, but I need to be able to just pass a regular expression along with the string.

Comment: You will run into too many cases. Cases for months with different number of days etc, and also `leap day` issues..

Comment: After a ton of googling, I found this beast of a regex: `/^(((\d{4})(-)(0[13578]|10|12)(-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((\d{4})(-)(0[469]|11)(-)([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|((\d{4})(-)(02)(-)(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|(([02468][048]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([13579][26]00)(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][0][48])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][2468][048])(-)(02)(-)(29))|(([0-9][0-9][13579][26])(-)(02)(-)(29)))(\s([0-1][0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))$/` from here [http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=178277](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=178277) .

Comment: I can't say that I understand it yet, but my initial tests works out.

Comment: The above string is incorrect for some date strings.  Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/sOTV9U

Comment: `strtotime()` in PHP does not eliminate February 30th
`php > print(strtotime('2019-02-30 22:22:22'));` out: `1551558142` which is Sat, 02 Mar

Comment: Upvoted; the simpler regex is useful for contexts in which you don't even particularly care whether the SQL date string is valid; just that it's the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for either 2019-04-30 or 2019-04-30 12:12:12

```
/^([1-2][0-9]{3})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])(?:( [0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/
```

It also has the advantage of not validating 0000-00-00